# R Shiny: How to Displayed values in filter with ascending Order

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard

How to Displayed values in filter with ascending Order.

Want to displayed filter of week in dataTableOutput with value in ascending order.

Here is the code of **ui.R**

```
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Delivery Assurance Matrix"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,

           selectInput("week_count",
                       "Week",
                       c("All",
                         sort(unique(as.character(data$Week))))
    ))),
 DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)
```

Here is the code of **server.R**

```
function(input, output) {
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data<-data
    if (input$week_count != "All") {
      data <- data[data$Week >= input$week_count,]
    }

    data
}))

}
```

But in UI Values not in ordering 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved by this changes.

```
fluidRow(
    column(4,

           selectInput("week_count",
                       "Week",
                       c("All",
                         order(sort(unique(as.character(data$Week)))))
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also you `shinyWidgets` package which has `Select All` Option

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

data <- c(11,1,2,3,10,21)
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Delivery Assurance Matrix"),
    fluidRow(
        column(4,
               pickerInput(
                   inputId = "week_count",
                   label = "Week",
                   choices = sort(data),
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(
                       `actions-box` = TRUE,
                       `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                       `select-all-text` = "Select All",
                       `none-selected-text` = "None Selected"
                   )
               )

               )),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)


server <- function(input, output) {}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]